# Approximate to the speed of Built-In functions

Tags: performance-tuning, number-theory

In *Mathematica*, there is a function `PowerMod[a,b,m]`, which computes `a^b mod m`. I will concern only this case: `b = -1, m is a power of a prime, say m = p^N`. When b=-1, the result of `PowerMod[a,-1,m]` is the number `a' such that a*a' = 1 mod m`, i.e the inverse of a in `mod m`.

There is a standard way to compute this inverse (when `m` is a prime power), but I will just give the code. The idea is to use Newton's method (in $p$-adic sense).

```
pAdicInverse[n_Integer,p_Integer,N_Integer]:=Module[

{stepMax,a,a0,x},

stepMax=Floor[Log2[N]]+1;
a=Mod[n,p^N];
a0=Mod[a,p];
x=PowerMod[a,-1,p];

Do[x=Mod[x*(2-a*x),p^2^i],{i,1,stepMax}];

x=Mod[x,p^N]

]   /;(PrimeQ[p] && N>=1)
```

This gives the correct answer, but the build-in `PowerMod[a,-1,p^N]` is 15x faster than the above code.

I would like to know how to speed up it. I thought to use something like `Nest` or `Fold`, but I didn't figure it out. The reason is that: In each step of `Do`, it works with different modulo `p^2^i`. Of course I can do it use the same modulo `p^N` all the time, but it will be much slower, even if I use `Nest`.

This is not really important, but I wonder how to speed it.

Comment: You will most likely not be able to match a specialized built-in (which may e.g. be implemented in C). You can try to `Compile` your code to speed it up, if you want to spend time on that.

Comment: Extended GCD methods might be faster (and that might be what `PowerMod` us using anyway).